# regex, java char + whitespace and char + symbol

Tags: java, regex, string

I am attempting to catch a few varieties of string, and each modification gets me one step forward, one step back. I need any string with pattern of multiple char + whitespace + char or char + non-alphanumeric + char. Basically, these instances would get caught:

```
w o r d 
w.o.r.d 
w_o_r_d 
w%o%r%d
```

but word w, word.w, or w.word should not get caught.

I have tried these various regex patterns:

```
(?:\S+\s){2}([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z0-9])+[a-zA-Z]+
[$-:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]
([a-zA-z][$-:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]^]{1})
```

They all get me MOST of the way there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The char in between would always be the same one? So none or dots or underscore or blank?

Comment: @janschweizer no could be any non alphanumeric symbol

Comment: Could you clarify what the pattern is? I don't understand "char or char".

Comment: or means i need scenario 1 or scenario 2 to be caught.

Comment: Please clarify you question. I thought it was ok, until tried to answer it.

Comment: i need a regex to find a word with spaces between each letter OR a word with nonalphanumeric between each char.

Comment: so in total input there's one of these words? Or is every word like this or... could you maybe just add more examples of possible input and desired output?

Comment: i will iterate over a list of phrases and each word will be analyzed, any word with symbols or spaces should be flagged

Comment: Not sure if that can be done with regex - as the typical delimiter between words would be space char. And some words are just one character long (I, a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following regex: 
`((\w[^a-zA-Z\d])+\w[^a-zA-Z\d]?)`

See the explanation here: 
https://regex101.com/r/pM1dV0/6

Comment: pretty neat, but I think for w1o2r3d4 it will fail

Comment: @Maddy the question says : char + whitespace + char or char + non-alphanumeric + char
w1o2r3d4 doesn't match the criteria which is expected.

cora for which case does it not work?

Comment: But it matches on the ones he said it shouldn't

Comment: @ashutosh this answer grabs an entire word, such as "test" as well as "t-e-s-t","t-test" and "test-t" which i do not want. I want "t e s t" and "t-e-s-t" but never "test".

Comment: @cora is `t.e-s_t` allowed?

Comment: @cora should `f.o.o b-a-r` be considered as one token or two?

Comment: @Pshemo two tokens as I will split a phrase. what is undesirable is foo.bar getting flagged as this is one token.

Comment: @cora Do you want to do every find in one regex or can we for instance split our tokens and test only those who contains few characters to see if they are in form `char[symbol]char[symbol]char` and so on?

Comment: I guess I can do these in 2 regex statements if necessary, the first from my original question finds the spacing as I need it, but no symbols.

Comment: This one would work ((\w[^a-zA-Z\d])+\w[^a-zA-Z\d]?)

Comment: @ashutosh this is the closest yet, i'll take it!

Comment: @cora is there a case where this doesn't work as well? I have updated my answer with the above regex btw.

Comment: @ashutosh well it's picky but the {2} in my first example up there is really looking to avoid flagging items such as "t e" or "test t e" -- i kind of want it to happen at least 3 times since i'm looking at titles that have versioning and it isnt that crazy to have word v 2

Comment: @ashutosh Shouldn't you leave off the last `[^a-zA-Z\d]`? You want it to end in a letter right?

Comment: @ashutosh actually added {2} gives me exactly what I want so this rules.

Comment: lol @JackmeriusTacktheritrix, you are so right.

Cora, please share the regex you are using finally.

Answer (score 1):

At current state of this question this seems to solve it:

```
String input = 
        "fo.o w o r d bar, " + 
        "fo-o w.o.r.d bar, " + 
        "f-oo w_o_r_d bar, " + 
        "fo_o w%o%r%d bar, " +
        "f.o.o b-a.r";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<=\\s|^)[a-z0-9]" +//start of the token
            "("+
              "(?<=\\s[a-z0-9])\\s[a-z0-9]" + //is continuation of `a b...`
              "(?=\\s|$)" + //and is not start of token like `x.y.z`
              "|"+
              "[^a-z0-9 ][a-z0-9]"+ //spaces are special, and are handled earlier
              "(?![a-z])" + //is not start of `aaa`
            ")+"//second part like _b must appear at least once
          ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
w o r d
w.o.r.d
w_o_r_d
w%o%r%d
f.o.o
b-a.r
```

(notice that `f.o.o` and `b-a.r` are handled as separate tokens)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
[\w][^[A-Za-z0-9][\w][^[A-Za-z0-9][\w][^[A-Za-z0-9][\w]
```

For testing you can also use below website :

http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Your regex will not compile in Java. Also there is no need for `[\w]`, simple `\w` is enough. Did you test your answer before posting?

Comment: @Pshemo : I tested my regex, seems to be working.. do you see any issues with it.

Comment: this does not give me the desired answer.

Comment: `[^[..]` is an issue in Java - each unescaped `[` need closing `]`. Since question was tagged with this language I suspect any solution should respect rules and limitations of selected language.